# Run all test in project using xUnit and TestDriven.net

Tags: testdriven.net, xunit

I know that very similar question was posted some time ago and it was even marked as answered, however the solution there does not seem to work for me.

I've installed `xUnit` using `NuGet`to my test project, wrote some tests and then decided I would like to run them somehow. I've turned my head towards `TestDriven.Net` which looked pretty good, so I installed it.
After that I've installed `xUnit` support for `TD.NET` using xUnit's installer. Everything went fine and installer marked `TD.NET` support as successfully installed. Yet, when I try to run all of my tests it fails (or rather do not find any tests in my test project, it displays that 0 success, 0 failures and 0 skipped tests were run).

Seems to me that `TestDriven.Net` is handling `xUnit` just fine (
 *"1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 1,75 seconds (xUnit.net 1.9.1 build 1600)."*, which I suppose means that it recognized `xUnit` tests).

I read about registry modifications, but everything seems fine there. Also, `TestDriven.net` author says that `xunit.dll.tdnet` should be enough for runner to recognize unit tests. This file is present in package folder created by `NuGet` but is not copied into `bin` folder. Should it stay where `NuGet` put it or should I place it somewhere else?

I would love to have it up and running so any help would be appreciated.
Cheers, Pako

Comment: Ok, I've found partial solution for my problem. The issue was not with `testdriven.net` or `xunit` but with `Solution Navigator` from `Productivity Power Tools`. For some reason it does not work with `TD.NET` correctly. But when I use `Solution Explorer` to run all tests in project, all test are found and run successfully. After that - tests from solution navigator run correctly too - at least until VS restart. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I noted above in comments to my question - the issue was not connected directly to `TestDriven.Net` and `xUnit`. It just seems that `TestDriven.Net` does not work properly with `Solution Navigator` from `Productivity Power Tools` extension to VS2010.

Simply running my tests form good ol' `Solution Explorer` works like a charm.